# (JavaScript) Write a function that takes two-word strings and returns True if both words being with the same letter

Tags: javascript

I have tried different methods, these are two of them but they don't really get me the result I need...

```
function twoWords(words) {

    let a, b = words.split(" "); 

    if (a == b) 
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

and

```
function twoWords(words) {

    let a, b = words.split(" "); 

    if (a(0) == b(0)) 
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

Comment: `let a, b = words.split(" ");` assigns b to the array of words, and declares a, with the value `undefined` ... you probably want `let [a,b] = words.split(" ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super close - use `a[0]` rather than `a(0)`. You’re trying to call a like a function - you need to access the first character like an array. Also note you need additional square brackets to properly destructure the variables:

```
let [a, b] = words.split(" ");

if (a[0] == b[0]) return true;
return false;
```

And you can even just do this (Jaromanda X's solution):

```
const twoWords = (words) => words.split(" ")[0] == words.split(" ")[1];
```

Comment: but `a` will be undefined, and `undefined` has no property `0`

Comment: or simply `return a[0] === b[0]` :p